# Possible to show Visual Studio debugging server over LAN?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2008

I am working on Windows Server 2008, and I am wondering if it is possible to show my debugging server to a peer over my LAN? What would I need to configure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you cannot show the built in debugging server anywhere other than localhost. To get around this I just added an entry to IIS and configured my network.

Thanks